# X be the normal space with arcwise connected. Then is there a continuous function from X onto I iff X has more than one point?

Tags: general-topology

It is definition of arcwise connected
$A$ space $X$ is arcwise connected if whenever $x, y \in X$, there is a continuous function $f:I=[0,1]\to X$ with $f(0)=x, f(1)=y$.

I don't know understand the question of 
"$X$ be the hausdorff and normal space with arcwise connected. Then is there a continuous function from $X$ onto $I$ iff $X$ has more than one point? What if $X$ is not normal?"

Does the inverse of $f$ be solution of question? Help me please

Comment: What you wrote is the definition of *path-connected*. For *arc-connected* we demand that $f$ is a homeomorphism to $f([0,1])$ (meaning $f$ needs to have a continuous inverse $f^{-1}:f([0,1]) \to [0,1]$).

Comment: @JensRenders umm.. Does any different if X is not normal space? I don't know what exactly this question is asking.

Comment: If $X$ is hausdorff, then arc-connected and path-connected are the same. Is it given that $X$ is Hausdorff?

Comment: @JensRenders Yes. I'm sorry for missing the condition. In quesiton, X is normal.

Comment: Normal doesn't imply Hausdorff. Also, the question asks about 2 cases, $X$ normal and $X$ not normal.

Comment: @JensRenders I think normal contains hausdorff in this book. So, X is normal then, X is hausdorff. So, this question asks about 2 cases, $X$ hausdorff and $X$ not hausdorff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be normal and arc-connected with more than 1 point. Take $x,y\in X$ with $x\neq y$. There is an arc $f:[0,1]\to X$ that connects $x$ to $y$. The arc $f$ is a a homeomorphism, so $f^{-1}:f([0,1])\subseteq X\to [0,1]$ is continuous and onto. By the [Tietze extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem) we can extend this map to the whole space to get a continuous map $X\to [0,1]$ which is clearly still onto.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Arc-connected (or path-connected) is not really needed. Connectedness is enough. We need $X$ to be $T_1$ plus normal (so $T_4$) in that case. Let $x \neq y$. Then $\{x,y\}$ is closed and discrete and by Tietze's theorem we can extend the function $f(x)=0, f(y)=1$ from $\{x,y\}$ to $[0,1]$ to a function $f:X \to [0,1]$. As $f[X]$ is connected and $0,1 \in f[X]$, $f[X] = [0,1]$, so we have a surjection onto $[0,1]$, as needed. (Nitpick: instead of $T_1$ we can get away with having two disjoint closed non-empty subsets that we can use instead of the singletons $\{x\}, \{y\}$).

Comment: I'm still in doubt that the original question assumed Hausdorffnes. Why else would they specify arc-connectedness? Anyways, do you know how to answer the part "What if $X$ is not normal"?

Comment: @JensRenders What does normal mean in you text ? Often it includes Hausdorff. If $X$ is not normal, it can fail.